# Delete directory and its subdirectories in one command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, automation, find

I am trying to delete empty directories in linux. Before doing this I am deleting files not accessed in last 7 days with following command

```
for x in $(cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd); do 
   if [ -d "/srv/${x}" ]; then
   find /srv/${x} -mindepth 1 -type f -not -amin -10080 -exec rm {} \;
   fi
done
```

Once the files are deleted, I want to delete empty directory. For this I am doing it following way

```
for x in $(cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd); do 
   if [ -d "/srv/${x}" ]; then
   find /srv/${x} -type d -empty -exec rmdir {} \;
   fi
done
```

I tried this on following dir structure

```
/srv/abc/
├── test1
│   └── test1       (This is File)
├── test2
│   └── test4
│        └── test2   (This is File)
└── test3
```

After executing /srv/abc -type f -exec rm {} \;
Now only directories are remaining

```
/srv/abc/
├── test1
├── test2
│   └── test4
└── test3
```

So I ran

```
find /srv/abc/ -type d -empty -exec rmdir {} \;
```

Now

```
/srv/abc/
└── test2
```

Then again

```
find /srv/abc/ -type d -empty -exec rmdir {} \;
```

So I want to delete all empty dir just in one command. I know here what is happening. When I first run `find /srv/abc/ -type d -empty -exec rmdir {} \;` It removes empty dir at that instance (which is test1 , test3, test2/test4 but not test2 )

So how do I remove test2 in same command if its subdirectories are also empty ?

Thanks

Comment: Note: `-not -amin -10080` can probably be replaced with `-amin +10080` (changing the `-` to a `+`).

Comment: You can't do that trivially; from the OS' (find's) perspective test2 (the directory at lvl 3) *isn't* empty, as it has an empty subdirectory in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rmdir` command has an optional `-p` or `--parents` option:

```
   -p, --parents
          remove DIRECTORY and its ancestors; e.g., 'rmdir -p a/b/c' is similar to 'rmdir a/b/c a/b a'
```

That option should do what you desire.

---

In your example directory...

```
/srv/abc/
├── test1
├── test2
│   └── test4
└── test3
```

Using `rmdir -p /srv/abc/test4` will remove the `test4` and `test2` directories, but not the `abc` directory because it still contains `test1` and `test2`.
From there, `rmdir -p /srv/abc/test1` will only remove `test1`, but after that, `rmdir -p /srv/abc/test3` will remove `test3` and `abc`.

Comment: After running find /srv/abc/ -type d -empty -exec rmdir -p {} \; I gor following message :                                                                                 rmdir: failed to remove directory `/srv/abc': Directory not empty
find: `/srv/abc/test3': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove directory `/srv/abc': Directory not empty
find: `/srv/abc/test1': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove directory `/srv': Device or resource busy
find: `/srv/abc/test2/test2': No such file or directory

Comment: How do I execlude /srv/ & /srv/abc/ from this list. I dont want to delete it

Comment: You should `cd` to `/srv/abc`, then use `find .` instead of the absolute path.  You could also suppress the "not empty" failures with `--ignore-fail-on-non-empty`.  See `man rmdir` for details.  If that doesn't work, you can always discard STDERR.